# How to pass table name as an input in dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a dynamic SQL procedure to get the first name given an ID.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SELECT_12 
(
  MIN_NBR NUMBER  
, BORR_FST_NM VARCHAR2  
, FIELD_NAME VARCHAR2
) IS 
TYPE cur_type IS REF CURSOR;
C_1 CUR_TYPE;
QUERY_STR VARCHAR2(1000);
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
QUERY_STR:= 'SELECT BORR_FST_NM from MON_DD_DDS.' || field_name ||'
 WHERE   MIN_NBR = :MINNBR';
   OPEN C_1 FOR QUERY_STR USING MIN_NBR;
LOOP
 FETCH C_1 INTO FIRST_NAME;
 EXIT WHEN C_1%NOTFOUND;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FIRST_NAME);
END LOOP;
NULL;
END SELECT_12;
```

I have different databases with the type MON_DD_DMS.STAGE_MRE_() where the bracket contains may different names like student, professor, scholar etc. I would like the user to define the name of the table like MON_DD_DMS.STAGE_MRE_STUDENT and MON_DD_DMS.STAGE_MRE_PROFESSOR etc.

When I try to run the procedure:

```
DECLARE
  MIN_NBR NUMBER;
  BORR_FST_NM VARCHAR2(200);
  FIELD_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  FIELD_NAME := &FIELD_NAME;
  MIN_NBR := &MIN_NBR;
  BORR_FST_NM := NULL;

  SELECT_12( MIN_NBR => MIN_NBR, BORR_FST_NM => BORR_FST_NM,
    FIELD_NAME => FIELD_NAME );
END;
```

it says that `STAGE_MRE_student` must be declared.

So is there something wrong I'm doing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `DECLARE
      MIN_NBR NUMBER;
      BORR_FST_NM VARCHAR2(200);
      FIELD_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
    BEGIN
      FIELD_NAME := &FIELD_NAME;
      MIN_NBR := &MIN_NBR;
      BORR_FST_NM := NULL;
  

      SELECT_12(
        MIN_NBR => MIN_NBR,
        BORR_FST_NM => BORR_FST_NM,
        FIELD_NAME => FIELD_NAME
      );
    END;`

Comment: That's the procedure I'm running and I get the following error:
"Identifier student must be declared"

Comment: Please edit the question to add extra information, particularly code, which needs to be formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be coming from your call, not the procedure. You're doing:

```
FIELD_NAME := &FIELD_NAME;
```

but you're assigning a string, so you need to have single quotes around the substitution variable:

```
FIELD_NAME := '&FIELD_NAME';
```

Unless you intend to add an OUT parameter you don't really need the local variables; you can do:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT_12( MIN_NBR => &MIN_NBR, BORR_FST_NM => NULL,
    FIELD_NAME => '&FIELD_NAME' );
END;
```

(and if you can get it on one line, or use a continuation character, you could use [`execute` in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm) as a shorthand for that anonymous block)

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented both the suggestions and it is working now.